# Coverting char array to double from read file

Tags: c, arrays, char, double

So I'm reading in a file of numbers separated by spaces and I'm trying to store these numbers into an array of integers. I'm doing something wrong though because I just keep getting zeros in the array.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *param;
    char temps[500];
    double holder[500];

    param = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    int u = 0;
    while ((temps[u] = fgetc(param)) != EOF)
        u++;
    char *pch;
    int v = 0;
    pch = strtok(temps," ");
    while (pch != NULL) {
        holder[v] = atof(pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL," ");
        v++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not adding a null terminator to `temps` when you finish reading the file.

Comment: Why not just use `fscanf("%f")` in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `nul` terminate the array for it to be a string in [c](/questions/tagged/c).

```
while ((temps[u] = fgetc(param)) != EOF)
        u++;
temps[u] = '\0';
```

not doing so and passing `temps` to `strtok()` invokes undefined behavior, and since it's undefined there is no way to explain the behavior of your program.

You should also:

1. Check the value of `argc` before trying to access `argv`.
2. Check the return value of `fopen()`.
3. Also, `fgetc()` returns `int` and not `char`, so `EOF` for example will cause problems with your code as it is, besides you don't wan't `EOF` to be in the array anyway.
4. Avoid mixing declarations with code for clarity.

This is your own program fixed, it should work correctly provided that

1. The input file exits and is readable.
2. The input file contains the appropriate data.

---

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *param;
    char temps[500];
    double holder[500];
    int u;
    char *pch;
    int ch;
    int v;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of arguments, a file path is expected.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    param = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (param == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error trying to open `%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    u = 0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(param)) != EOF)
        temps[u++] = ch;
    temps[u] = '\0';

    v = 0;
    pch = strtok(temps, " ");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        char *endptr;
        holder[v] = strtol(pch, &endptr, 0);
        if (*endptr != 0)
            fprintf("warning: these characters were not convetible -- %s\n", endptr);
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");

        v++;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is certainly a bug in his program, why would it cause the specific problem he's having?

Comment: @Barmar Undefined behavior?

Comment: Minor: Suggest `int ch; while ((ch = fgetc(param)) != EOF) { temps[u] = ch; u++; }` for the usual `fgetc()` return type reasons.

Comment: @chux Absolutely right, should put that in the list of fixes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use fscanf to read the double value in a single loop. Dont know what the correct seperation should be here so using space.

```
while ((ch = fscanf(param,"%lf ", &holder[v] )) != EOF)
    v++;
```